# Python Code or Alternatives for Splitting Up a Table

Tags: python, database, split

I'll try to explain this my best.

I have one table that I am trying to break down into a smaller one. The table has LOT numbers and OWNERS as the column headers. The LOT numbers can sometimes have multiple owners ie John and Peter own Lot 12345. Therefore in the table it was have the same LOT number twice with a unique OWNER.

ie     LOT     OWNER

```
  12345    John
  12345    Peter
```

What I want to do is to display the unique LOT number, and the OWNERS combined into the same column.

ie     LOT     OWNER

```
  12345    John, Peter
```

I really just want to make my table smaller by changing the relationships. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as I am not the strongest on the Python/Programming/Development side of GIS.

Comment: it's not clear in what format do you keep the table? is it a type of DB? postgres? noSQL? is it an excel talbe in a local file? a remote file? is it in a csv?

Comment: You can create a dictionary whose keys are lot numbers and the value is a **list** of owners (even if it is just one). But note that the structure you are after, while more compact, is not a useful schema for a database table: DO NOT write a list of names into a single database table value.

Comment: Sorry, essentially we are just doing this to make the table smaller my reducing the number of rows due to many owners owning the same property.  This is being done in SQL.  There are also several other columns, but Im just curious as to how I can combine the OWNERS into one entry per LOT number.

Comment: We really need to know what database system are you using: mssql, mysql, oracle or other?

Comment: MySQL.  Sorry.  And I will try that Jarek. D thank you!

Comment: Every query you do against the owners now will have to be a "like".  This is probably not a good idea. If this is what you want, you are better off doing the group_concat inline in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this (if you're on MySQL):

```
SELECT lot, GROUP_CONCAT(owner) FROM your_table GROUP BY lot;
```